# How to pass an argument to NppExec in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I'm new to Notepad++. Can someone tell how to pass an argument when I execute NppExec in Notepad++? For instance, I want to run `print @ARGV` through Notepad++. What parameter should I use so that I can enter my argument when I click F6? I know `"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`. But it doesn't seem to work for passing an argument. Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to the array variable list in perl? Make your question clearer by stating an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way of executing perl scripts with input arguments to the script using NppExec plugin in Notepad++. This will give a message box that asks you to enter arguments to pass to the script.

You can leave out the "echo" line, this is just so you can see what  the input to the script is.

Change your current settings under "NppExec -> Execute..." to:

```
inputbox "Script arguments : "
echo Script input arguments, @ARGV : $(INPUT)
perl "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" $(INPUT)
```

Hope this helps.